# c# Unable to stop windows service

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I have a Windows service which triggers a thread on `OnStart(string[] args)`. There are other threads created by this main thread. After installing and starting the service, when I try to stop the service I am unable to stop the service during the first attempt. When I right click on my service and request 'Stop'. I get the below exception and the service is still running.

> Windows could not stop the service on Local Computer. The service did not return error. This could be an internal windows error or an internal service error.
>   If the problem persists, contact your system administrator.

When I try to stop it again, I end up with other message as

> Windows could not stop the service on Local computer.
>   Error 1061:  The service cannot accept control messages at this time.

but service is stopped. So I am performing right click -> Stop, twice to stop a service.

I tried to abort thread and stop the service as below but no gain.

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    onStartThread.Abort();
    Log.AuditEventLogger("Service Stopped");
    this.Stop();
}
```

I highly appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Out of interest how do you start your thread? Is it a background thread? If not you might need to make it one - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx

Comment: See if this other question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885080/c-sharp-windows-service-not-running-correctly

Comment: protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {


            onStartThread = new Thread(() =>
            DataFeedScheduler.Start());
            onStartThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
            onStartThread.Start();}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you are calling `this.Stop` which will then call your `OnStop` method again. You have an infinite loop so your service is not stopping.

Secondly, don't go aborting your threads like this. Signal for them to stop  e.g. using a wait handle (`ManualResetEvent`) and join the thread. If you are using tasks then use a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: Exactly this is what I did wrong. I tried ServiceController stop and this.Stop, both doesn't work. Once I removed stop() its working as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code snippet in the comments I'd suggest making your thread a background thread. By default I believe it will be a foreground thread, and so if it is busy will stop your proecess terminating.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) for more detail.

However, as you haven't provided a great deal of detail in the question there may well be other factors in play too.

Answer (score 0):

```
onStartThread.Abort();
```

Will not necessarily always abort the thread.
When a call is made to the Abort method to destroy a thread, the common language runtime throws a ThreadAbortException. There is no guarantee that the thread will ever end. If you want to wait until the aborted thread has ended, you can call the Thread.Join method. Join is a blocking call that does not return until the thread actually stops executing.